# Is there any method to execute whenever scheduled jobs only when i run "rails server" command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, schedule, whenever

I create a whenever scheduled task + ActiveJob job.

I configure config/initializers/scheduler.rb like this:

```rb
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ScheduleJobManager.new # 创建定时任务
end
```

This job will running, no matter what command i type. like rails db:migration, rails server...

I just expected it running when I type "rails server"

Comment: What you did here is run `ScheduleJobManager.new` when Rails initializes. Not sure what you intend to do, but probably look into something like Foreman https://github.com/ddollar/foreman or Overman https://github.com/spinels/overman. Beware, both are unmaintained

Comment: Could you use a module to extend the `rails s` command found in `rails/commands/server/...` to run after the server goes up?